# Add node to Dojo tree

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo, dom-node

I have a Dojo tree and I am trying to add a node at the end. I tried to update the store by below code. Though store got updated by tree did not show the new node.

```
this.virtualtree.model.store.put({type:"form",parent:"wpRoot",id:"ABC",name:"ABC"});
```

Later I tried using PasteItem function on model. Below is the code. Still it is not working.

```
this.virtualtree.model.pasteItem({"type":"form","parent":"wpRoot","id":"ABC","name":"ABC"},window._self.virtualtree.model.root,window._self.virtualtree.model.root,true,9,true);
```

Please let me know how to modify the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `dojo/store/Observable` in combination with `store.add()`
HAve a look at dojo online documentation: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tree.html#id7

And see below for a working example:

```js
require([
    "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Observable",
    "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", "dijit/Tree",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(win, Memory, Observable, ObjectStoreModel, Tree){

    // Create test store, adding the getChildren() method required by ObjectStoreModel
    var myStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            { id: 'world', name:'The earth', type:'planet', population: '6 billion'},
            { id: 'AF', name:'Africa', type:'continent', population:'900 million', area: '30,221,532 sq km',
                    timezone: '-1 UTC to +4 UTC', parent: 'world'},
                { id: 'EG', name:'Egypt', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                { id: 'KE', name:'Kenya', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                    { id: 'Nairobi', name:'Nairobi', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                    { id: 'Mombasa', name:'Mombasa', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                { id: 'SD', name:'Sudan', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                    { id: 'Khartoum', name:'Khartoum', type:'city', parent: 'SD' },
            { id: 'AS', name:'Asia', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
                { id: 'CN', name:'China', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'IN', name:'India', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'RU', name:'Russia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'MN', name:'Mongolia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
            { id: 'OC', name:'Oceania', type:'continent', population:'21 million', parent: 'world'},
            { id: 'EU', name:'Europe', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
                { id: 'DE', name:'Germany', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'FR', name:'France', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'ES', name:'Spain', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'IT', name:'Italy', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
            { id: 'NA', name:'North America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
            { id: 'SA', name:'South America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' }
        ],
        getChildren: function(object){
            // Add a getChildren() method to store for the data model where
            // children objects point to their parent (aka relational model)
            return this.query({parent: object.id});
        }
    });
    myStore = new Observable(myStore);
    // Create the model
    var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: myStore,
        query: {id: 'world'}
    });

    // Create the Tree.
    var tree = new Tree({
        model: myModel
    });
    tree.placeAt("test");
    tree.startup();
  
    myStore.add({id: 'foo', name:'Added after tree creation', type:'continent', parent: 'world'});
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div class="tundra">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```